# WPF - How can I generate a file inside the directory where the program is installed?

Tags: c#, json, xml, wpf, visual-studio

I'm trying to create a WPF application to do some of the time consuming QA tasks easier. Now I ran into problem of creating a file that would be used for configuration of some operation via ssh. This file will contain default configuration, however it might be updated by the user with new values.

I changed the properties of a file to "Build Action - Content" and "Copy to Output Directory - Always" however when I publish and install the application the file is not in the directory.

How can I make the file appear in the output directory and be available for some changes?

Comment: Why not use the app.config file to store this additional info, rather than creating a separate config?

Comment: How do you "publish and install" the application?

Comment: The point was to create a file in any form (txt, xml, json) that can be easily accessed by QA team. So let's say that I have some default values as 1 and it is good for majority of runs, but for one run they want to change them to 4. i don't want to create a lot of input boxes for values that might be never changed.
For publishing I just go in Visual Studio to Build -> Publish and then in the publish directory use setup.exe to install it.

Comment: What you just described can be accomplished by using the app.config file as suggested by @KevinCook.

Comment: @Qucu: If you look in the Application Files/app folder, is your file included? Perhaps it has a `.deploy` extension.

Comment: @mm8 Exactly it is there with .deploy extension.

Comment: We like to use a folder under program data for configuration/files that are to accessed/edit by the user as the user permissions are a bit less restrictive then in Program Files

Comment: Can you show me what a structure of that would look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The published files get a `.deploy` extension by default. This is a setting that can be changed under Project->Publish->Options->Deployment in Visual Studio.

If you uncheck the `Use ".deploy" file extension` option and re-publish, you should see and be able to use the content file in the Application Files/app directory of the output folder.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will ask another one in that case.

Comment: Please ask a new question if you have another issue. Don't ask additional questions in the comment field.